# Angular set color depending if true or false

Tags: angular

I'm currently building a todo app as a learning project. When I display my todo list I want the background of the list item to have a green background if the the task is completed and red if it isn't.

This is how the list looks like at the moment:

[image]

This is my .html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-12 col-sm-12">
            <ul class="event-list"  *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
                <li>
                    <time datetime="">
                        <span class="day">{{todo.dueDate | date:'EEE'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.dueDate | date:'LL'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.dueDate | date:'LLL'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.taskCompleted}}</span>
                    </time>

                    <div class="info">
                        <h2 class="title">{{todo.taskName}}</h2>
                        <p class="desc">{{todo.extraNote}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="edit" style="width:33%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="confirm" style="width:34%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="delete" style="width:33%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my idea was to have a loop go through if the todo boolean is true then it is green and else it would be red. But I can't find a way to get it done...

EDIT:
I've added this to my .css:

```
.green {
    background-color: rgb(39, 142, 255);
}
```

And this is my current .html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-12 col-sm-12">
            <ul class="event-list" *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
                <li
                        *ngFor="let todo of todoList"
                    [ngClass]="todo.taskCompleted ? 'green': 'red'">

                    <time datetime="">
                        <span class="day">{{todo.dueDate | date:'EEE'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.dueDate | date:'LL'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.dueDate | date:'LLL'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.taskCompleted}}</span>
                    </time>

                    <div class="info">
                        <h2 class="title">{{todo.taskName}}</h2>
                        <p class="desc">{{todo.extraNote}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="edit" style="width:33%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="confirm" style="width:34%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="delete" style="width:33%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!---<li>
                    <time datetime="">
                        <span class="day">{{todo.dueDate | date:'EEE'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.dueDate | date:'LL'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.dueDate | date:'LLL'}}</span>
                        <span class="month">{{todo.taskCompleted}}</span>
                    </time>

                    <div class="info">
                        <h2 class="title">{{todo.taskName}}</h2>
                        <p class="desc">{{todo.extraNote}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="edit" style="width:33%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="confirm" style="width:34%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="delete" style="width:33%;"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>--->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use NgClass? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass or https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Or even [style.background-color]="todo.taskCompleted?'green':'red'"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two different CSS classes for both the scenarios and then use `ngClass` and supply the class based on a condition `todo.taskCompleted`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-12 col-sm-12">
      <ul class="event-list">
        <li 
          *ngFor="let todo of todoList"
          [ngClass]="todo.taskCompleted ? 'green': 'red'">
          ...
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `[ngClass]="todo.taskCompleted ? 'green': 'red'"` syntax that will apply the CSS class of `green` if `todo.taskCompleted` resolves to `true` and apply the CSS class of `red` otherwise.

All you need to do now is create two CSS classes named `red` and `green`.

**PS** - I've added the `*ngFor` on `li` instead of `ul` because that's where it needs to be as that's what we want to repeat.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todo-list-ng-class?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer I understand the idea behind your suggestion. I can't manage to set the background color though. Is there anything I've done wrong? (I've edited my first post)

Comment: I've added a Sample StackBlitz. Please check it in working. Most probably there's some issue with your CSS.